# Show an <i> tag only when is ordered

Tags: html, css, angular

My table component has implemented methods that order, and filter itens from API.

I'm using in the moment a simple way to hide the  tag. My  looks like:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
      <th (click)="setOrderBy(attr.value)" scope="col" *ngFor="let attr of filteredAttribsList"  >
        {{ attr.name }}<i *ngIf="isOrdered" class="fa fa-sort orderable" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">Opções</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

Although the use `*ngIf` directive hide the  tag, the `*ngFor` overlap and make it for all itens in , i want to show the  tag only for the ordered column. I'm using this to change the value of isOrdered

```
if (!this.isOrdered) this.isOrdered = true
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you only gone to order by single attribute value just set isOrdered to the attribute value

*template*

```
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th (click)="setOrderBy(attr.value)" scope="col" *ngFor="let attr of filteredAttribsList">
        {{ attr.name }}<i *ngIf="isOrdered == attr.value" class="fa fa-sort orderable" ></i>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">Opções</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
```

*component*

```
setOrderBy(value) {
   this.isOrdered = value;
}
```

and if you want to support multiple attribute  values

*component*

```
isOrdered = {};

setOrderBy(value) {
    this.isOrdered[value] = !this.isOrdered[value];
}
```

*template*

```
<thead>
  <tr>
   <th (click)="setOrderBy(attr.value)" scope="col" *ngFor="let attr of filteredAttribsList">
        {{ attr.name }}<i *ngIf="isOrdered[attr.value]" class="fa fa-sort orderable" ></i>
      </th>
      <th scope="col">Opções</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
```

finally if you want to reset so clear all attributes

```
reset(){
   this.isOrdered[value]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`isOrdered` as Array should do the trick.

```
isOrdered = new Array();

ngOnInit() {
    for(let attr in filteredAttribsList) {
        this.isOrdered[attr.value] = false;
    }
}

setOrderBy(value) {
    for(let attr in this.filteredAttribsList) {
        this.isOrdered[attr.value] = false; // make sure that there is only 1 true
    }
    if (!this.isOrdered[value]) this.isOrdered[value] = true;
}

<i *ngIf="isOrdered[attr.value]" class="fa fa-sort orderable" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

Comment: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

Comment: You can use the index instead of the attr.value. `*ngFor="let attr of attrList; let i = index"` Then in the template `*ngIf="isOrdered[i]"`

You might also want to update the array initialization and use indices when accessing array elements in the setOrderBy() function.

`setOrderBy(index: number)`

Comment: @DarleisonRodrigues You can do what Keenan Diggs suggested . Error that you posted is just about types in TypeScript.

Comment: @DarleisonRodrigues Create StackBlitz with example from your question.

Comment: @Oen44 sorry, i didnt try the coment.